# Universal HTML form validating, jQuery preferable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I want to do a form validating in the most common way. Is there a tool for that, maybe, jQuery plugin?

For instance, for the following rules:

1. All textboxes should not be empty
2. If 'Show License' checkbox is checked, 'I accept' should be checked too.

the validating expression will go like '`input:text:[value=""], input:checkbox:checked#showlicense ? input:checkbox:unchecked#iaccept : nothing`'.

I'd be happy to implement this on jQuery selectors (returning invalid controls), but I don't know how to implement conditions.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look for jquery validate plugin, its already out there..

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: Looks a bit ugly. $(".selector").validate({
   rules: {
     contact: {
       required: true,
       email: {
         depends: function(element) {
           return $("#contactform_email:checked")
         }
       }
     }
   }
})

Comment: OK, I'll better search for a conditional jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate(){
var flag = true;
$('#yourformid > input').each(function(){
 if($(this).val() == ""){
   flag = false;
 }
});

if($('#showlicense ').is(':checked')){
   flag = false;
    if($('#iaccept').is(':checked')){
       flag = true;
    }


}
 return flag;

}
```

Usage

```
<form onsubmit="return validate()" ....>
```

Comment: This way is not common at all. I can implement custom checking for every individual form (even more, I've done 2 forms validation), but am looking for an expression-based validation.

Answer (score 0):

I've found jQuery selectors can be easily customized:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities/

I'll create my own validator based on :if-modified jQuery selector expression returning "invalid" controls.